# Handwritten English Character Data Set..Where to get (and openly available)

Tags: image-processing, dataset, handwriting, icr

We have created a Handwritten Character Recognition system and now want to test the system on English characters (both digits and alphabets).
For digits, we have performed our testing on MNIST data set.
However for the English alphabets we have not been able to find any openly available (i.e. available for free), standard data set. All we have been able to find is [NIST](http://www.nist.gov/srd/nistsd19.cfm) and [CEDAR](http://www.cedar.buffalo.edu/Databases/CDROM1/) handwritten data sets, available on their respective official sites, but they come at a substantial cost.

Is there any other, openly available standard data set of English alphabets which can be used for testing the Handwritten Character Recognition system.

Comment: Yes...please see my answer below.

Comment: See the [HASYv2 dataset](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.08380) (I'm the author)

Comment: Do check an image dataset at https://www.kaggle.com/sachinpatel21/az-handwritten-alphabets-in-csv-format it contains A-Z handwritten 370000+ images

Comment: This is what you may be looking for : https://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/image-group/emnist-dataset

Answer (score 24):

Did you check the UCI Machine Learning repository?
http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html

What about this one? 
http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/UJI+Pen+Characters

This is what you may be looking for:
https://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/image-group/emnist-dataset

Comment: Should be marked as solution

Comment: How do I read the EMNIST data? It's not PNG or anything.